# parsing date and time

Tags: xslt, transformation

Currently  In my source file, i am getting date and time values like below. 
2010-07-06T19:06:47

i want to put date in one variable and time in another one. Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the combined date/time value is in variable `$date-time`...

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($date-time, 'T')"/>
<xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-after($date-time, 'T')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel, 
It's working.  
Can you please also assist me with the following Issue. 

My source file look like below

</StsRsn>
<AddtlStsRsnInf>/00000002/Level 2 Reject</AddtlStsRsnInf>
<AddtlStsRsnInf>The Transaction Reference Number is</AddtlStsRsnInf>
<AddtlStsRsnInf> not unique.</AddtlStsRsnInf>
</StsRsnInf>  

Now requirement is to concatenate the <AddtlStsRsnInf> value into one single varaible.   

Thanks in Advance, 
Kiran.

Comment: @Kiran: please ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way to do this would be to split/explode the variable into 2 pieces with the date in one and the time in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Date Parsing means converting String into Date. Same Simple DateFormat codes are used to parsing date.

For example,

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");<br/>
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("07/16/87");<br/>
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");<br/>
date = (Date)formatter.parse("16-Jul-87");<br/>
```

Source : [Tutorial Data - Date and Time](http://tutorialdata.com/java/dateandtime.html)